# What is a Chaotic Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Chaotic Word™.

You can use the following examples below to find the rule:

| CHAOTIC™ | NON-CHAOTIC™ |
| --- | --- |
| CLUE | HINT |
| THEN | NOW |
| MONKEY | CHIMP |
| BUG | ANT |
| SHOE | BOOT |
| WET | DRY |
| THIRTY | FORTY |
| ANTILOPES | AEGILOPS |
| SKILL | EFFORT |
| ZOMBIE | GHOST |
| VOICE | ACCENT |
| SURGERY | BIOPSY |
| COMPLETE | ALMOST |
| SUCCESS | ACCESS |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
CHAOTIC™, NON-CHAOTIC™
CLUE, HINT
THEN, NOW
MONKEY, CHIMP
BUG, ANT
SHOE, BOOT
WET, DRY
THIRTY, FORTY
ANTILOPES, AEGILOPS
SKILL, EFFORT
ZOMBIE, GHOST
VOICE, ACCENT
SURGERY, BIOPSY
COMPLETE, ALMOST
SUCCESS, ACCESS
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Non-Chaotic word is one in which

> all the letters appear in alphabetical order.

and a Chaotic word

> doesn't have the letters appear in order.

example:

> Chaotic - Clue: E comes after U,
>  Non-Chaotic - Hint: All the letters are in alphabetical order